# grep : Find occurances of 3 consecutive alphabets

Tags: sed, grep

I want to find aaa, bbb etc
I've tried :

```
grep -E [a-z]\{3\} 1.txt
```

but this even prints abc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use references to capturing groups:

```
[/tmp] cat test.txt                                                            
aaa
bbb
abc
aab
bbc
[/tmp] grep -E "([a-z])\1{2}" test.txt                                         
aaa
bbb
```

`\1` refers to the stuff captured by `([a-z])` (a single letter, in your case), so the regex looks for a single letter followed by the same letter two more times.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant :

```
grep '\([a-z]\) *\1\1' fileName
```